# How to turn tuple of tuples in unicode to pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, unicode, pandas

so I got connection to database and using fetchall() to pull my data

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = """
SELECT name, n
from table
"""
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall(

)
```

my rows resulting in tuple of tuples I am trying to get this to dataframe with column name

I have tried to use below but

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['name', 'n'])
```

but got error : ***DataFrame constructor not properly called!***

rows ((u'a', 1.0), (u'b', 2.0), (u'c', 3.0))

the value came in unicode , but I just want my dataframe to be something like this below, any suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It is probably more performant to load the df directly from SQL: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why don't you just use [`pd.read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.sql.read_sql.html):

```
sql = "SELECT name, n from table"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, connection)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your tuple into a list with `list(rows)`

```
>>> rows = ((u'a', 1.0), (u'b', 2.0), (u'c', 3.0))
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(list(rows), columns=['name', 'n'])
>>> df
  name  n
0    a  1
1    b  2
2    c  3
```